# Global scope variables from within a function - Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I need to return a value from within a function and that function pdf.create().tofile() always returns undefined. Now if I explicitly try to return a variable by making it global, I am not able to do it in typescript. Can someone help? Please refer as below:

```
var serviceS3Result: any;
await pdf
  .create(stocksReport({}))
  .toFile(`./dist/test.pdf`, async (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('hi from inside', res);
    serviceS3Result = await this.s3Service.uploadFileFromSystem(
      `test`,
      fs.readFileSync(`./dist/test.pdf`),
      `test.pdf`
    );
    fs.unlinkSync(`./dist/test.pdf`);
  });
return serviceS3Result;
```

this returns `undefined`, any idea why?

Comment: which library is used for `pdf`? At least from the snippet, it looks like the operation `toFile` accepts callback...

Comment: @NalinRanjan Sorry I did not mention it, it is the 'html-pdf' 
 -  [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf?activeTab=readme) no it does not accept a callback only the HTML and the format of the converted pdf as said in the document.

and yes toFile() accepts a callback but that is always returning undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `.toFile` call does not return a `Promise`, so `await` is actually useless here.

So the solution here is to wrap the call into a `Promise` then resolve the value:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pdf.create(stocksReport({}))
        .toFile(`./dist/test.pdf`, async (err, res) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            console.log('hi from inside', res);
            // The promise fulfills here
            resolve(await this.s3Service.uploadFileFromSystem(
                `test`,
                 fs.readFileSync(`./dist/test.pdf`),
                 `test.pdf`
            ));
            fs.unlinkSync(`./dist/test.pdf`);
        });
});
```

Comment: Small mistake: instead of `res(await ...` it should be `resolve(`

Comment: Good that you addressed the `err` handling as well in inside the callback.

Comment: @Taxel, KhanhBao.. Awesome! Thanks a lot! Learned something today.